# CosmosDB partition key value length

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I've seen a lot written about choosing good partition keys in CosmosDB, but I was wondering whether there are advantages to short or long partition key values? Obviously particularly long ones will make the documents longer, which will consume more RUs, but other than that, does it make any difference?

Comment: Have you enabled support for large partition key on your Cosmos DB container?

Comment: Partition key values are all about getting a good partitioning distribution, combined with most common lookup requirements. Partition key length should only be a secondary concern, but there is support for longer partition keys, if you need it. There are docs that talk about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of the partition key value itself doesn't have a direct impact on performance or scalability.
The length of your partition key value is just one factor to consider when choosing a partition key for your Cosmos DB container. The most important thing is to choose a property that has a number of distinct values and lets you distribute your workload evenly across these values.
[Choose a partition key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#choose-partitionkey)

Comment: important sentence: "it is always recommended to configure your container with support for large partition keys." That is, there should be no notable downside.